# How to delay angularJS interpolation intentionally

Tags: angularjs, interpolation

Say I have the below html:

```
<div>{{name}}</div>
```

I want to delay the interpolation on `{{name}}`, so that I can see the curly bracket on html(raw data).

My first thought is to create an attribute directive called pause, and in the compile function of this directive, just call `$timeout` to pause for a while.

The `html` should look like this, the `10000` is the pause interval.

```
<div pause="10000">{{name}}</div>
```

However it didn't pause, is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: So you purposefully want to see the curly brackets for, say, 10 seconds? Just want to make sure I'm clear. Also, can I ask the purpose of this in your context?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The context is there is a defect in our project raised up against this issue, we decided to use ng-cloak to fix this issue, it is fixed. However the quality process in our project requires a test case to validate the fix, this interpolation slowness is not happening everytime, so we need a way to reproduce the interpolation slowness constantly, so that we can validate our fix. I know it sounds silly but we have very strict QA process rules.

Comment: Thanks for replying. That's very interesting. So really the broader question is trying to figure out the best way to test that ng-cloak is working in an automated test?

Comment: It doesn't have to be an automated test. But yes, it also helps make sure the root cause of the slow interpolation is due to angularJS, not some other reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the `ng-non-bindable` to an element prevents the interpolation of the element's contents.

From the [AngularJS docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngNonBindable):

```
<div>Normal: {{1 + 2}}</div> <!-- 3 -->
<div ng-non-bindable>Ignored: {{1 + 2}}</div> <!-- {{1 + 2}} -->
```

To delay the process, your custom directive could add the `ng-non-bindable` directive to the element initially and remove it after a timeout.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! It's really smart